# how to get to a specific part of this nested array/object

Tags: php, xml, arrays, object

This is driving me crazy, I am trying to get to a specific part of this object and it is driving me crazy, here is the object contents:

```
XMLHandler Object
(
    [doc:XMLHandler:private] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [state] => Live
                )

            [newsListItem] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [href] => http://api.contentplus.co.uk/6cb5ea15-d6b1-4c40-9db7-cb2a3315080b/news/800773226/
                                )

                            [id] => 800773226
                            [publishDate] => 2011-10-24T10:04:49
                            [lastModifiedDate] => 2011-10-24T11:20:40
                            [headline] => Relationships matter on social media
                        )

                )

        )

    [format] => html
)
```

I want to get the value of `[id]` I am trying to access it like this:

```
echo $niList->doc->newsListItem[0]->id;
```

but this is giving me nothing, I know I am close (well I hope I am) but I just cant quite get it right, could anyone help please.

Thanks all.

Comment: Try `echo $niList->newsListItem[0]->id;`

Comment: that didn't work either, thanks :) - correction, my code sees it as a valid statement but it does not get any results,

Comment: @Gordon I am not 100% sure, I have been given some code (that I didn't write) that grabs the contents of an XML feed, it is currently written using `DOMDocument`, but I am having to convert it to use the `Curl Library` and `SimpleXMLElement`. So you think I need to access it through $this or get it outside of doc as it is private?

Comment: @AdriftUniform that depends on what you want to do with it. If you need it outside you have to have an accessor of some kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object dump says

```
doc:XMLHandler:private
```

which means `doc` is a **private property of XMLHandler**. As such, you can only access it from within that object via `$this`. But you are trying to access it from outside the object when you do

```
echo $niList->newsListItem[0]->id;
```

This wont work. Add a method to that XMLHandler object that does what you want to do with that newslistitem id. Also see the chapter on Visibility in the PHP Manual:

- http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php

Comment: I see, thanks Gordon, I will work out getting it outside of that and making it public, also see my comment above. cheers